# How can I parse the json body from from an Akka Client-Side HttpResponse

Tags: json, scala, akka, akka-http

I'm using Akka's HTTP client library to request a json, and I want to use Play Framework's [play-json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaJson) to parse the json. After I get Akka's `HttpResponse`, I don't know how to parse the json from the response body, and I don't know how to pass the json to another function in the `onComplete` directive. Instead, I get this error

```
overloaded method value parse with alternatives:
[error]   (input: Array[Byte])play.api.libs.json.JsValue <and>
[error]   (input: java.io.InputStream)play.api.libs.json.JsValue <and>
[error]   (input: String)play.api.libs.json.JsValue
[error]  cannot be applied to (scala.concurrent.Future[String])
[error]           val usefulInfo = Json.parse(data)
[error]                                 ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

What I'm trying right now:

```scala
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpRequest
import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshal
import play.api.libs.json._

object Main extends App {
    // Boilerplate code from Akka's documentation
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    // needed for the future flatMap/onComplete in the end
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

    val request = HttpRequest(
        method = HttpMethods.GET,
        uri = "http://example.com/somedata.json"
    )
    var response: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(request)
    response.onComplete{
        case Success(res) => {
            val data = Unmarshal(res).to[String]
            val usefulInfo = Json.parse(data)
            println(usefulInfo)
        }
        case Failure(e)   => println(e)
    }
}
```

Questions I have are:

1. How can I parse the json after the Future resolves, with Play Framework's `Json.parse()`?
2. How can I store or use this json elsewhere after the `response` Future resolves? Do I need to do something in the `Success` case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `Unmarshal` returns a `Future` so you need to process the data inside the `Future` to get the `String` value.

If you want to keep the result rather than just print it, use `tranformWith` on the initial result rather than `onComplete`:

```
val result = Http().singleRequest(request)
  .transformWith {
    case Success(res) =>
      val data = Unmarshal(res).to[String]

      data.map { d =>
        val usefulInfo = Json.parse(d)

        println(usefulInfo)

        usefulInfo
      }
    case Failure(e) =>
      println(e)

      Future.failed(e)
  }
```

Note that this becomes much cleaner if you leave the printing until the end:

```
val result = Http().singleRequest(request)
  .flatMap { res =>
    Unmarshal(res).to[String].map { data =>
      Json.parse(data)
    }
  }

result.onComplete {
  case Success(js) =>
    println(s"Success: $js")
  case Failure(e) =>
    println(s"Failure: $e")
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! This is exactly what I needed. So what is the difference between using `onComplete` vs `transformWith` in this case?

Comment: `transformWith` returns a new `Future` whereas `onComplete` does not return anything. So `onComplete` is only useful for side effects like printing or sending a message.

Comment: Do you know where I can find documentation on "arrow functions"? In the `transformWith` you just left `usefulInfo` as a single variable. Is this how "arrow functions" return values? Does it have something to do with the functional nature of scala?

Comment: `usefulInfo` is actually inside the function that is passed to the `map` call on the unmarshaled data. In the second example I just return the result of `parse` directly, but in the first case I need to keep it so that I can print it out and then return it as the result of the function. Scala allows very concise code but does take some getting used to!